# get GTM container's version in client-side (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm in the process of migrating existing tracking scripts from a custom implementation to GTM.

One requirement is that during our deployment process, the existing script disables itself and let GTM track instead. In theory this can be done by detecting the GTM contaner's version and disabling based on that number.  That way the switch over can occur by simply publishing within GTM.

I have found no documentation on `gtm.js` but from parsing the minified script and inspecting live JS objects in Developer Console the only thing I've found so far is that the container version is included in a comment at the top of the script like:

```
// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
// Container Version: 9
```

Another thing I've tried is traversing the DOM and getting the GTM `<script>` tag but how can I get the contents of the script (where the comment will be).

```
// using jQuery
$("script").filter(function(i, scr) {
    var src = $(scr).attr('src') || '';
    return src.indexOf('gtm.js?id=') >= 0;
});
```

This is obviously not ideal as the underlying GTM implementation can change at a moment's notice, but it may work as a one-off.

Please chime in if anyone has any ideas

Comment: Are you trying to get the version (as in your first example) or the container id (because it looks like this is what your second example does) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff the first example code shows the script contents, and the second is an attempt at that content programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Still a fair question, because as far as I know, the container version is not readable outside the tag manager. Also, the version comment as in the original post is no longer available,

I'm in the same situation, as an external script needs to be able to know the current container version for some sort of a/b test or blue-green deployment.

One solution could be a custom html tag that writes/pushes the built-in variable `Container Version` into the data layer:

```html
<script>dataLayer.push({"gtm_container_version": {{Container Version}} });</script>
```

and later read in an external script like:

```js
dataLayer.find(data => data?.gtm_container_version)?.gtm_container_version;
```

Customise it to your needs. And I remember there was an internal way to push data into the data layer, but I couldn't find it.